# RobotFramework: how to put a value of an page id in a variable?

Tags: robotframework

the web page has an element with an id

> id:igtxtctl00_wtbHouseNumber

I want to use  *should match* or  **Should Match Regexp**
but the arguments are: Arguments: `[string, pattern, msg=None, values=True]`

So i can't use  should match regexp     **id:testid**     pattern

Comment: Why cant you use `Should Contain` keyword?

Answer (score 0):

what I needed was this first:

```
${value2}=  get value  id:tbHouseNumber
```